# Different sums by adding the currency.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How many different sums can be formed by the following
>   $5$ dollar, $1$ dollar, $50$ cents, $25$ cents, $10$ cents, $3$ cents, $2$ cents, $1$  cent.

As there are $8$ different things and at least one is to listed I thought it would be

$\dbinom{8}{1}+\dbinom{8}{2}+\dbinom{8}{3}+\cdots+\dbinom{8}{8}=2^{8}-1$

But their could be double counting as $3$ cents=$2$ cents+$1$  cent.

I think I need to subtract the dupliction.

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: Should it be 5 cents rather than 3 cents? I don't know of a currency that has a 3 cents coin...

Comment: You need to clarify how many coins are allowed to be used. Exactly two coins? Any number of coins? Can each one be used exactly once only or can it be used more than once?

Comment: @tomi, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-cent_piece_(United_States_coin)

Comment: @BarryCipra I guess so, of course back then in the UK we had threepenny and sixpence coins, too.

Comment: @tomi: Whether I need to use exactly 2 or more that I need to find from the context of the question , as I see it is not explicitly given but it seems I can use at least one up to eight.

Comment: A brute-force solution is given by counting the number of monomials in the expansion of:
$$ (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^{10})(1+x^{25})(1+x^{50})(1+x^{100})(1+x^{500}).$$

Answer (score 2):

Apart from 3 being equal to 1+2, every other number is larger than the sum of all smaller ones. So that is the only source of double-counting.

There are $2^5$ sums that have 3 but not 1 or 2 since you can use any combination of coins with values larger than 3. Similarly there are $2^5$ coins that have 1 and 2 but not three. So the answer is
$$2^8-1-2^5.$$

Comment: Can u elaborate in detail how $2^{5}$ comes.

Comment: As before, you can choose whether or not to put each of the resting five quantities:
$$
\dbinom{5}{0}+\dbinom{5}{1}+\dbinom{5}{2}+\dbinom{5}{3}+\dbinom{5}{4}+\dbinom{5}{5} \space= 2^{5}
$$